# How to make DataTables pagingType:input property to read only?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I wanted to know if there is a way to make the `DataTables` input property to read only.I want to show the page number but don't want the user to change the page number.

This is my JQuery and pagingType is input

```
var table = $('#esignTable').DataTable({"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
      pagingType: 'input',
      pageLength: 5,
      language: {
        "sEmptyTable": " ",
        oPaginate: {
            sNext: '<i class="fa fa-forward"></i>',
            sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-backward"></i>',
            sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>',
            sLast: '<i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>'
        }
      }   
    });
```

I want the highlighted part to be read only.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: inspect element -> class or id name -> jquery $(classname).attr("disabled", "true");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this line to your datatable function and it will do what you want.

`pagingType: 'input disabled',`

Or you can get a class name for that textbox and then using jquery it can be made readonly.

```
$(".classname").attr("readonly",true);
```

Comment: Himanshu, i've already tried this for fun and it doesn't work. I should have posted this already.